# process does not exit after last (non-blocking) line

Tags: node.js

I am wondering what determines if node process will not finish after the last (non-blocking) line.

I know one scenario is when using timers, node keeps track of the timer references and won't exit until those are gone as [documented](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout).

What other scenario are there?

For example, when looking at this code from the [fastify docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Getting-Started/#your-first-server), it's not clear to me what keeps the program alive. Since none of the ways to call listen, shown there, blocks. You can execute some code afterward.

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  logger: true
})

fastify.get('/', function(request, reply) {
  reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
})

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, function(err, address) {
  if (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
})

// this actually runs, so the listen call 
// appears to be non blocking
console.log("why no exit?")
```

The same goes for the async version, from the docs, which doesn't await the call to `start`, and yet the program doesn't exit.

I have poked around in the codebase to see if there are timer created but I didnt spot anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another scenario to prevent the process from exiting is having open sockets that are still being listened on, like the one created by `fastify.listen()`.

That call is asynchronous, so non-blocking, hence the next line gets executed.